# Connecting to Guest Machine

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I've been looking for a while now and I can't seem to find the answer anywhere, so here goes the question.
I have a VirtualBox Running Ubuntu 10.04 and routed as Nat at the moment. I want to be able to access this server from my Lan Network, but the setting are off quite a bit at them moment.
My IP in Ubuntu shows up as 10.0.2.0, this is odd for one reason because I was expecting a
192.168.1.X Number to appear as it's internal IP address. The second issue is that if I try to connect to the SQL or Apache server on 10.0.2.0 it doesn't connect to it; at this point I've been searching the internet for about 3 1/2 hours and have not came any closer to a resolution and if someone can spot an issue or needs more info then please help me out; getting frustrated at this point. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had and still have similar problem, but on Windows 7 (host) and Windows 8 (VM). They said install Guest Additions, but after I did that my VM didn't start at all. [Here](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html) is a link about guest additions on various OSs.

Comment: Alright, so after looking around a little bit; one of my initial configurations had actually worked; I set the network up as an internal network and it gave it a real internal IP. The internal IP doesn't show up on the router, but it's better then nothing; I'm assuming when I get to the point where I'm getting static IPs things will go a bit smoother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need the VM set up with "bridged networking" instead of NAT in order for it to appear on and be accessible from your LAN

https://askubuntu.com/questions/52147/how-can-i-access-apache-on-virtualbox-guest-from-host

Comment: That's been the only way to connect to it. The LAN won't acknowledge that it's on the network, so it can make it a pain to setup forwarding, but it is still possible as the VM seems to get a static internal IP. Thanks for the help.